# CSS background image onclick

Tags: jquery, css

```
#header{  
    height: 80px;
    padding-left: 208px;
    background-image: url("Trans.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
} 
<div id="header">
<!--display something float to the right-->
</div>
```

How can I bind the background image onclick event?

```
$("#header").delegate(":image", "click", function() {
//this does not work
});
```

neither this work :(

```
$("#header:image").click(function() {}
```

TIA

Comment: note that .delegate has been replaced by the .on method. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a background-image is no element in the DOM - you can not bind an event to it.
why do you want to do that?

If you want to track clicks only on the non-repeating background - bind your event to the header and then get the x-y coordinates of the click do the math.

Or - add another div inside with the exact dimensions and position of your background, add the event (and maybe even the image) to that div.

Comment: I got your point. Actually, I just kind of lazy, since I have the css background image as something like logo, I was wandering if I can click on that image to switch back to main page. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since the image appears as background for your div, bind event on div instead:

```
$(document).delegate("#header", "click", function() {....});
```

Also notice that `delegate` has been superseded by [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler.

```
$(document).on("click", "#header", function() {....});
```

Comment: @JoshuaM, No it has not been replaced .delegate method calls the .on !

Comment: Well, yeah... `.delegate()` has been aliased to `.on()` but the point is that you're supposed to phase out `delegate` in favour of `on` because it is on the path towards deprecation. "Don't use delegate from jQuery 1.7 onward" is the takeaway. Note also that Sarfraz is using `document` as the listener because the markup is an unknown commodity. But you should use the closest ancestor that is not a candidate for being destroyed by DOM manipulations.

Comment: @EvilP: replaced == superseeded. It still exists, but for proper usage, you should be using .on

Comment: Thanks for the update on the .delegate(), 
As I mentioned, inside the #header div, I would have display something float to the right for example...
 <div id="header"> 
 <div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Action1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Action2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Action3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ActionX</a></li> 
  </ul> 
 </div> 
</div> 

Thus, I am thinking if I can bind only on the background image (which it won't fall to the .menu)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="header" onclick="function()"></div>
```

Comment: he is talking about eventbinding and you'r suggesting to go 10 years back in time and use an onclick-attribute?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#header").click(function(){
        $('#header').css("background",":url('diff.jpg')");
});
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#header").click(function(){
    $(this).css("background-image","<url>");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('img').click (function(event){
var image_link = $(this).data('img');
$("body").css("background-image","url('"+image_link+"')");});
```

it is good

```
<img data-img="1.png" background-image:url("1.png")>
```